# Logging from Custom Tensorflow Op (Issue with VLOG)

Tags: tensorflow

I have defined my own tensorflow op and in it I use `VLOG` however when  I try to run the Op I get:

```
NotFoundError: dlopen(/Users/alex/git/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/my_op.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZN10tensorflow8internal10LogMessage12MinVLogLevelEv
  Referenced from: /Users/alex/git/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/my_op.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/alex/git/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/my_op.so
```

What is the suggested way logging from within custom ops?

I have included:

```
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/logging.h"
```

Comment: So it looks like it compiled but the symbol is not accessible during runtime. The visibility of symbols exported through pywraptensorflow.so is limited during linking (ie, [tf_exported_symbols.lds](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/754048a0453a04a761e112ae5d99c149eb9910dd/tensorflow/tf_exported_symbols.lds) ). Not exactly sure where this symbol is getting filtered out, but the fact that it's called  tensorflow::internal::... suggests that it's not meant to be exposed as an API, so you may be limited to printf here

Comment: How did you make you operator `so`?  with gcc or bazel?

Comment: Bazel following instructions on tensorflow docs.

Comment: Would you please share your operator code?

Comment: Posted on TF tracker: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8241